# How can two separate phases interact with each other in an separatory funnel

Tags: solubility, phase

Hello I was thinking about the following process.

I was working in the lab, and synthesized a chelator for various metals, iron, copper etc.; however, when extracting the mixture with water and ethyl acetate, the organic layer remained green. This made sense as the procedure for the chelator called for a copper (I) catalyst.

So to get rid of the copper (I) ions, I thought it would be a good idea to wash the organic layer with dipotassium EDTA. It actually got rid of the copper (I) and turned the organic layer brown (my chelator’s own color).

My question is now, how did this actually work? Water and ethyl acetate (to my knowledge) are in a good approximation not really soluble in each other. But how did the EDTA get the copper ions out of my chelator which was in the organic layer? I get that EDTA probably has a higher complexation constant than my chelator, but the EDTA solution couldn’t have diffused into the ethyl acetate (because it was charged, 2-).

But the resulting EDTA-Cu complex should be better soluble in water that’s for sure.

So by what mechanism does this work in general?

Comment: Did you shake the sample?

Comment: You can research interfacial diffusion in liquid-liquid extractions, finding papers like [this one](https://aiche.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/aic.15636). Well, abstracts.

Comment: And here is a [book chapter](https://uomus.edu.iq/lecture/12%203%202019%2010%2029%2007%20AM982@Lec-2%20Mass%20Transfer-Basic-a.pdf) from a chemical engineering lecture introducing some quantitative models.

Comment: Just a sidenote, but water and ethyl acetate *are* substantially soluble in each other, just not infinitely. There are immiscible ratios, but [roughly 5% of each solvent goes into the other phase](https://macro.lsu.edu/howto/solvents/ethylacetate.htm). Compare with [water and hexane](https://macro.lsu.edu/howto/solvents/hexane.htm), where the values are ~0.01%.

Comment: I did shake the sample.